# Can a Tab Bar contain a "play" button

Tags: ios, swift

In my Tab Bar, I have a "My favorites" and "About Us" icon.  These go to different View Controllers.  I have made a UIButton that plays an audio file.  How do I add that button to the Tab Bar at the bottom?

So when the button is tapped, it plays on the current scene, and does not go to a new scene.

Comment: Can? Yes. Should? Terrible user experience and abuse of everything the user expects from the standard iOS controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent a tab from opening it's view controller by subclassing UITabBarController and implementing `tabBarController(_:shouldSelectViewController:)`. From there you could perform your play action.

[More on UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:)

In Swift your subclass would look like the following

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        let tabIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers?.indexOf(viewController)

        if tabIndex == 2 {
            // Perform your play action here
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I set the delegate on the CustomTabController?

Comment: You can set the delegate in `viewDidLoad` or another initializer with `self.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a your tabBarController which has several buttons. each button has a tag. so, you can judge the button which you can't go to a new controller.